# What is the sum of Psi/Digamma-function of consecutive arguments? Is there a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, special-functions, closed-form

In a consideration of summation of a series
$$ s  = a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \cdots  \tag 1$$ with $$\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k=0$$
but slowly decreasing, the coefficients $a_k$ are somehow related to $1/k^2$ but with some tricky disturbance; but actually I expect that finally $s=\zeta(2)$.

At the moment I observe empirically (based on the first 64 terms) that the coefficients $a_k$ could be nicely separated into the components 
$$ a_k = b_k + r_k \\
\text{ where } \\
 b_k= - {\psi(1+k)-\log(1+k)  \over 1+k } \tag 2 $$ (with $\psi()$ being the digamma-function) and the residuals $r_k$ decreasing rapidly to zero. So if also the series $$B= \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k \tag 3$$ is convergent and has a closed form I could check the result $s-\zeta(2)$ by the rapidly converging residual series $R=\sum_{k=0}^\infty r_k$

So my question is:

> ***Q1:*** does the sum $B$ as defined in (3) and (2) have a closed-form expression and if: which?

---

*[Update]*
Using W/A I get the interesting powerseries (around $x$ at $\infty$) for each term
as 
$$ \begin{eqnarray} 
 {\psi(x)-\ln(x)\over x} 
   &=& \frac{-1}{2x^2}+\frac{-1}{12x^3}+\frac{1}{120x^5}
   +\frac{-1}{252x^7}+\frac{1}{240x^9}+\frac{-1}{132x^{11}}+\frac{691}{32760x^{13}} 
+ \cdots \\
 &=& {\zeta(0)\over x^2}+{\zeta(-1)\over x^3}+{\zeta(-3)\over x^5}+{\zeta(-5)\over x^7}+ \cdots
\end{eqnarray}
$$
and if that can be summed over consecutive $x$, we had the expression for $B$ as
$$ B = - (\zeta(0) \cdot \zeta(2)+\zeta(-1) \cdot \zeta(3)+\zeta(-3) \cdot \zeta(5)+  \cdots ) \underset{\mathfrak N}{=}   0.91624014984...$$
where $ \mathfrak N$ means Noerlund-summation and I used 64 terms for that zeta-sum. This gives $11$ consistent digits which agree to @Kirill's computation.
Moreover, if I compute inversely $B =  \zeta(2)-R$ I arrive at the same value for $B$ ***to all digits*** as given by Kirill *(except for the sign - I've corrected a sign-error in the above definition of $b_k$ after Kirill had used the original (erroneous) one)*

Comment: It would be helpful if the downvoting could be explained and I could see the problem with that question.

Comment: Do you have a reason to expect a closed form? It is probably easier to work with $$B = \int_0^1\left(-\frac{\gamma+\log(1-z)}{1-z}+\frac{\ell(z)}{z}\right)\,dz $$ where $\ell(z) = \partial_\mu|_{\mu=0}\mathrm{Li}_\mu(z)$.

Comment: @Kirill: you are right, I do not actually have a reason that there is a closed-form, I just hoped for it because the summation by the series itself is very slow. It slowly increases above, for instance after 3600 terms, $ B_{3600} = -0.916101277030...$ and by that steady (but decreasing) growth it is possibly related to the first derivative $\zeta'(0) =-0.91893853... $

Comment: It is $-0.916240149844295830534809275625733388801447182393876137844189\ldots$, so it's definitely not $\zeta'(0)$. In fact, I'd say the log term is harder than the digamma term.

Comment: @Kirill: ahh, good to know. Thanks!

Comment: If what you want is a numerical value for the original sum, it is probably easier to evaluate it directly numerically. I usually use sage and mpmath, which is included in sage.

Comment: @Kirill: well, I'm looking at a family of similar series of this type and I hoped to get a key-idea - ideally getting some closed-form from where I could proceed with a reasonable direction. I firmly think, that the $B$ and $R$ sums add up to the $\zeta(2)$ but it would be better to have some analytical relation - generalizable to the related series for which I think I'll get $\zeta(3)$ and so on.

Comment: @Kirill, are you sure of all those digits you quoted? My own experiments of summation + extrapolation only seem to guarantee the first six significant digits of your result, which makes me suspicious of your other digits.

Comment: @J.M. I got those by evaluating the integral for $B$ from a comment above with mpmath (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/305d829237190ca66058), not by summation, which would be much harder I think (especially since the sum is not alternating).

Comment: A new Noerlund-sum with 256 terms give the following approximations: $ \\ $ $\small {0.91624014984429583053 5130417000 \\
  0.91624014984429583053 5096294860 \\
  0.91624014984429583053 5065662601 \\
  0.91624014984429583053 5038351368 \\
  0.91624014984429583053 5014232057 \\
  0.91624014984429583053 4993035757 \qquad \text {term 255}\\
  -------------------------------- \\
  0.91624014984429583053 48092756257333 } $  $ \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  $  where the last number is that of Kirill